# browser can't open my image connected to my sever

Tags: c, linux, browser, server

the image "http://localhost:8882 /img.jpg" cannot be displayed because it contains errors

i'am trying to build an HTTP server i connect to the browser with the same port the browser opens a .txt file or a directory but i get the message above when i try to open an image i don't have any idea why

iam trying to read and and write at the same time due the size of the image

```
  int send_file_request(int fd, char *path,int content_length,int size)
    {
             int fd1;
char date[128];
char buf1[4000];
char *mime = get_mime_type(path);
        char* request_shape="HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
          "Server: webserver/1.0\r\n"
          "Date: %s\r\n"
          "Content-Type: %s\r\n"
          "Content-Length: %ld\r\n"
          "Connection: close\r\n\r\n%s";

          char* request_shape_no_mime="HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
          "Server: webserver/1.0\r\n"
          "Date: %s\r\n"
          "Content-Length: %ld\r\n"
          "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";

            int len=size+strlen(request_shape)+strlen(date)+100;
          char*buf=malloc(len);

          if(mime==NULL)
            sprintf(buf,request_shape_no_mime, get_current_date(date,                sizeof(date)), content_length);
        else
      sprintf(buf,request_shape, get_current_date(date, sizeof(date)), mime, content_length);
  write_to_socket(fd,buf);

     if ((fd1 = open(path, O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
    perror("open error when transfer file");
}
      int nread;
    while ((nread = read(fd1, buf1, sizeof(buf1))) > 0) {
    if (nwrite(fd, buf1, nread) <= 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "nwrite error when transfer file.\n");
        return -1;
    }
}
       free(buf);
   return 0;
              }
```

*the nwrite function*

```
 ssize_t nwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
 {
  int nwrt;
const char *ptr = buf;
size_t nleft = count;

errno = 0;
while (nleft > 0) {
    if ((nwrt = write(fd, ptr, nleft)) > 0) {
        nleft -= nwrt;
        ptr += nwrt;
    } else if (nwrt == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "connection has been closed.\n");
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;
        perror("write");
        return -1;
    }
}
return count;
```

}

the browser should dispaly the image but it dosn't

Comment: I see a big possible problem in some of the code you *don't* show: How do the `write_to_socket` function know how many bytes to send? Remember that `read` can read *less* than the requested number of bytes, and that it will not null-terminate the data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i updated the code

Comment: Check your `request_shape` and `request_shape_no_mime` format strings. Count the number of format specifiers. Count the number of arguments provided to the `sprintf` calls. Do it all match?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if there is a problem with the shape then normal files shouldn't work but it do work

Comment: The `request_shape` format string have *four* format specifiers, including a trailing `"%s"`. The corresponding `sprintf` have *three* arguments. That leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It could even lead to buffer overflow. I'd say it's *unlucky* your program haven't crashed.

Comment: Oh and please stop using `sprintf` unless you know 100% *exactly* that the resulting string will fit in the buffer. Otherwise use `snprintf` which includes a size-argument to stop buffer overflows.